# a cardinal notation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

How it follows [here](https://books.google.cz/books?id=DLCyehuI0i0C&pg=PA57&dq=%22in+1980+shelah+established+the+general+result+that+for+any+limit%22&hl=cs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMjqWI-Nz6AhWSgv0HHTWhDDUQuwV6BAgIEAg#v=onepage&q=%22in%201980%20shelah%20established%20the%20general%20result%20that%20for%20any%20limit%22&f=false) from
$\aleph_\delta^{\operatorname {cf}(\delta)}<\aleph_
{(|\delta|^{\operatorname {cf}(\delta)})^+}$ that $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{(2^{\aleph_0})^+}$
and how was strong limiteness of $\aleph_\omega$ used ? I've just tried to plug into the first formula $\omega$ for $\delta$ but the result is still unclear to me.